# Trying to understand what this means: re= /([^=&]+)(=([^&]*))?/g

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to JavaScript and I am really lost on what this code does:

```
var re = /([^=&]+)(=([^&]*))?/g;
while (match= re.exec(qs))
{
var key= decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g,' '));
var value= match[3] ? QueryString.decode(match[3]) : '';
if (this.dict[key])
    this.dict[key].push(value);
else
    this.dict[key]= [value];
}
```

In particular, can someone explain what this `var re = /([^=&]+)(=([^&]*))?/g;` part of the code does?

Comment: That's a regular expression.

Comment: [Explained: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%2F%28%5B%5E%3D%26%5D%2B%29%28%3D%28%5B%5E%26%5D*%29%29%3F%2Fg](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%2F%28%5B%5E%3D%26%5D%2B%29%28%3D%28%5B%5E%26%5D*%29%29%3F%2Fg).

Comment: A really good resource to visualise regular expressions is http://www.regexplained.co.uk/.

Comment: @DavidThomas you should have provided that as answer, it would be accepted

Answer (score 3):

This code uses [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to take a query string and parse out individual parameter keys/values, turning them into an object for ease of use.

Comment: The OP clearly hasn't discovered regular expressions so I doubt he understands what "RegEx" is or how it matches anything.

Comment: @GeorgeReith, That's why I linked to a basic reference.  If someone could provide a better specific explanation, I'd happily upvote it.  He wanted to know what it did, so I offered a contextual explanation.

Comment: Edited to be a bit more verbose.

Comment: You hadn't linked at the time. I was just warning about using an abbreviation and technical terms to explain a concept that someone is unfamiliar with.

Comment: @GeorgeReith, Ah, that makes sense.  +1 for your more detailed explanation.  Whoops, now your answer is gone.  Woot for real-time Stack Overflow!

Comment: hi thanks for the information, so what exactly do we want to do a search on in this? var re = /([^=&]+)(=([^&]*))?/g  <-- is there a character or phrase we are searching for ?

Comment: @fishman, See DaveThomas' link:  http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%2F%28%5B%5E%3D%26%5D%2B%29%28%3D%28%5B%5E%26%5D%2A%29%29%3F%2Fg  The to summarize, the match is for keys/values in `someKey=someValue&someOtherKey=someOtherValue`.

Answer (score 2):

That is a Regular Expression.

They are a string of characters which allows you to match patterns in other strings to perform complex searches on bodies of text.

In the case above the regular expression is designed to match parameters in a query string allowing you to perform functions on each one individually.

Check this site out for tutorials and reference on using regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Regular Expression.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) These are commonly used to filter out strings/inputs to make sure that they meet your requirements when it comes to user-inputs (ie. "The password must contain characters, numbers, etc..." but done programmatically )

As one of the comments stated in your original post, [this](http://www.regexplained.co.uk/) is a good place to "visualize" how these work more easily.